# How to take private key from "SSH Username with private key" Global Credential in Jenkis

Tags: python, jenkins, private-key

I have an "SSH Username with private key" configurated in Jenkins(myKey) and a not-pipeline job that runs a python code from a repo.

The following is a piece of code:

jenkins_private_key = os.environ['myKey']

private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(jenkins_private_key)

In the above line I got the following error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

My question is: How can I get the private key from credentials in some readable format that paramiko can get me the "real" private key?

Thanks

Leandro

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this same issue and I made it work by using instead the [from_private_key_file](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/keys.html#paramiko.pkey.PKey.from_private_key_file) method, because when you are setting the credentials in the Jenkins job the key input label reads "**Key File Variable**", hence the file method.

Bear in mind that if it has a passphrase, you have to pass it too to the method

```
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY = os.environ['SSH_PRIVATE_KEY']
SSH_PASSPHRASE = os.environ['SSH_PASSPHRASE']

private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(SSH_PRIVATE_KEY)
# Or if it has a passphrase
private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(SSH_PRIVATE_KEY,
                                                    password=SSH_PASSPHRASE)
```